# How to get gmail notification without polling

Tags: notifications, gmail, xmpp, push-notification

I need to get gmail or other emails like yahoo/hotmail (new email)notifications from the server without polling. Since am building it on a cross platform mobile app polling or persistent connection is not a ideal way of doing it. What is the best way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

idk if it is a pc platform you are talking about,but in general you could open a server on the client that will be open to receive a message if there is a new mail. then on receiving this message you can download the new mail or whatever